# How do I monitor the availability of an internal tcp port in New Relic?

Tags: newrelic

I'm looking for the functional equivalent of check_tcp in Nagios? Additionally, the tcp port that is to be monitored is only accessible from an internal network, not from the public. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've heard, [NR may have a solution by the end of this year](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/availability-monitoring-on-internal-websites/1918).

Another option is to [create your own plugin](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugins/developing-plugins/structuring-your-plugin/checklist-developing-plugins):